# MVC Page Load from History

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a dashboard page. When I login in for the first time I want to load from server.Then we want to maintain the same sate whenever we come back to that page. When we are refresh the page then we want to load the Dashboard  again.

```
We don't want to load page every time from the sever. User  wants to load the page ,he click the refresh button and load the data again. We are using **ASP.NET MVC 3.**
```

Advance thanks.Plz help me.

Comment: mb some code and more details from it

Comment: please add code and what you have tried already - that will improve your question.

Comment: You might be able to use cache, and then recache the cache when clicking the refresh button?